# Issues when downloading file from Slim Framework

Tags: php, download, slim

I want to download file through Slim Framework (The reason why I'm using Slim Framework is because I want to write a simple REST API). I found this post:
[Download file from Slim Framework 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911530/download-file-from-slim-framework-2-4) and this post: http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/359-file-download. I followed the method. Here is my code:

```
$app->get('/download/:id', 'authenticate', function($id) use ($app)
{    
    $log = '../download/'.$id.'/myfile.zip';

    $res = $app->response()->headers();
    $res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
    $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    $res['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment; filename=' . basename($log);
    $res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary';
    $res['Expires'] = '0';
    $res['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate';
    $res['Pragma'] = 'public';
    $res['Content-Length'] = filesize($log);

    readfile($log);    

    // NOTE: 
//        $response = array();
//        $response["error"] = false;
//        echoRespnse(200, $response);

});
```

I'm using the Google Chrome's Advanced Rest Client application to test. The problem is the browser hung after the file downloaded.If I comments out the NOTE part in my source code, the browser won't hang again. But I got a "Unexpected token P" error.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the solution here: [PHP readfile() adding extra bytes to downloaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041564/php-readfile-adding-extra-bytes-to-downloaded-file?answertab=active#tab-top).

You lack the calls to ob_clean, flush and exit.

The problem might be becasue of extra characters output with the rest of the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

For Slim 3, I had a bit of struggle.
I struggled with this in Slim 3.0.
I was trying something like the following and the pdf binary was getting displayed on the screen.

```
$header['Content-Description']  = 'File Transfer';
$header['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' .basename("$file") . '"';

// ...
$response   = $response->withHeader($header);
```

In order to make it work, you need to set the key/value pairs using `$response->withHeader()`. And it works like a charm. For example:

```
$response   = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' .basename("$file") . '"');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Expires', '0');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Pragma', 'public');
$response   = $response->withHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a little late but you can use this package for slim http file response :
https://github.com/mhndev/slim-file-response

Answer (score -1):

Is the solution above working for you? Here's my code, which just outputs obscure characters directly into the browser window:

```
$app->get('/file/:fileid', function($fileid) use ($app)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipname = "zipfile3.zip"; // Zip name
    $zip->open($zipname,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $files = array ( "sprecher_inserts_en_VB.doc" );

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $path = "uploads/".$file;
        if(file_exists($path)){
            $zip->addFromString(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path));  
        }
        else{
            echo"file does not exist";
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
    // after that, the zip file is on the server and valid when downloaded manually (e.g. by entering its URL directly)

    $res = $app->response()->headers();
    $res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
    $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    $res['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment; filename=' . basename($zipname);
    $res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary';
    $res['Expires'] = '0';
    $res['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate';
    $res['Pragma'] = 'public';
    $res['Content-Length'] = filesize($zipname);

    ob_clean();    
    flush();
    readfile($zipname);    
    exit();
});
```

The output in the browser window is the following, no dialog for downloading the file is loaded whatsoever:
[image: Output of the code shown above]